# The difference between dist functions in r

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, vegan

I want to calculate the dissimilarity indices on a binary matrix and have found several functions in R, but I can't get them to agree. I use the jaccard coefficient as an example in the four functions: `vegdist()`, `sim()`, `designdist()`, and `dist()`. I'm going to use the result for a cluster analysis.

```
library(vegan)
library(simba)

#Create random binary matrix
function1 <- function(m, n) {
  matrix(sample(0:1, m * n, replace = TRUE), m, n)
}
test <- function1(30, 20)

#Calculate dissimilarity indices with jaccard coefficient
dist1 <- vegdist(test, method = "jaccard")
dist2 <- sim(test, method = "jaccard")
dist3 <- designdist(test, method = "a/(a+b+c)", abcd = TRUE)
dist4 <- dist(test, method = "binary")
```

Does anyone know why `dist1` and `dist4` are different from `dist2` and `dist3`?

Comment: Have you studied the documentation? If that didn't provide the answer, have you studied the source code?

Comment: And then you are forgetting the package stringdist :-). which has a metric for doing a jaccard distance, but based on q-gram profiles.

Comment: I have not been able to get an answer to my question from the documentation and I'm not so strong in reading source codes, which is why I hope for you guys help.

Comment: If you want to use binary dissimilarities in **vegan** `vegdist`, you have to say so: Use `vegdist(test, method="jaccard", binary=TRUE)`. Your equation for `dist3` defines *similarities* instead of **dis**similarities. For dissimilarity, use `designdist(test, "(b+c)/(a+b+c)", abcd=TRUE)` or `1 - designdist(test, "a/(a+b+c)", abcd=TRUE)`. Judging from the name, `sim` function also defines similarities. In **R**, you normally need dissimilarities in cluster analysis, at least when using standard tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I put this as an answer as well. Here the main comments for the dissimilarities you calculated:

- `dist1`:  you must set `binary=TRUE` in `vegan::vegdist()` (this is
  documented).
- `dist2`: `simba::sim()` calculates Jaccard similarity and you must use `1-dist2`. The `?sim` documentation gives a wrong formula for Jaccard similarity, but uses the correct formula in code. However, the documented formula defines a similarity.
- `dist3`: Your `vegan::designdist()` formula gives Jaccard similarity and you should change it to dissimilarity. There are many ways of doing this, and the code below gives one.
- `dist4`: this is correctly done.

Replacing your four last lines with these will do the trick and give numerically  identical results with all functions:

```
#Calculate dissimilarity indices with jaccard coefficient
dist1 <- vegdist(test, method = "jaccard", binary = TRUE)
dist2 <- 1 - sim(test, method = "jaccard")
dist3 <- designdist(test, method = "(b+c)/(a+b+c)", abcd = TRUE)
dist4 <- dist(test, method = "binary")
```

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't aware of the differences between the functions (similarity or dissimilarity).

Comment: All standard **R** tools assume you have **dis**similarities. This is a design choice. Some other software have different design choices, but while in **R** do the **R** way.